# iterating through a List<> using foreach loop in message.body while sending mail?

Tags: html, asp.net, generics

in my asp.net application im sending a mail , which checks the list of employees eligible for promotion and sends that Employees List

I need it in this pattern

```
 The following Employees Are eligible for promotion:

 xyz
 abc
```

The employees names are in a list, i need to use foreach loop inside msg.body and iterate through that list but its giving me some syntax errors, is it possbile to loop in html?

```
msg.Body = "The following Employees Are eligible for promotion <br/><br/>Employee Name: '"  "'";



this is my List
      List<string> myList = UserForPromotion.Split(',').ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to build the message body. First make sure you have this statement at the top of your .cs file:

```
using System.Text;
```

then iterate through `myList` like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("The following Employees Are eligible for promotion <br/><br/>Employee Name:");
foreach (string name in myList)
{
    sb.AppendFormat("<br/>{0}", name);
}

msg.Body = sb.ToString();
```